# QGIS Scale Problem (it starts with 0.000xx)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale, dxf

Iam new here and i'm beginner of QGIS..

My problem is the Shapefiles i have is very very small, the scale is starts with 0.0000xx.

please help ASAP. it so very important in our Municipality.

Comment: I have no idea why this would be a problem? You can just zoom in on the small features.

Comment: our Municipal Boundary are on 1:10,000 scale. When I overlay the other shapefiles (cadastral) it is very small or it's like a dot. in QGIS...  please help..

Comment: It is probably in the wrong projection. You should start by reading: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_projections.html and https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html

Comment: Maybe the shapefiles have wrong units. GIS data is usually in meters or degrees, while CAD data may be in millimeters. What is the extent of your data, as reported by rightclick on the layer, properties, Metadata tab?

Comment: Hi good day, sorry for the late reply.. here is the extents of the shapefiles... Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 821111.97,955284.65 : xMax,yMax 821112.06,955284.70
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: This is really small indeed. You mght have imported a scaled CAD map. You need to import an unscaled map, where all units are meters. So my best try is to unscale the geometry in the CAD system before feeding it to QGIS.

Comment: thank you sir. i already converted Shapefiles to CAD file using the Online converter i had search in google and i had been also installed autocad 2014 in my computer. Now, the problem is, i don't know what is the next step or what type of tutorial to make me guided. please help me sir.. thank you and God bless in Jesus Name Amen...